# Appearance of text and programs looks horrible after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: resolution, windows-10

Today I upgraded from Win7 to Win10.

Some programs like Steam, but also Windows programs like the device manager, have a different resolution then normal (1920x1080). The text and pictures (also the Steam Icon in the Taskbar) look horrible. Also when I install anything, the menu looks horrible.

In Firefox, Word and most Windows stuff, it looks normal. So it's not a general problem of resolution. And it never happened with Windows 7 before.

[image: screenshot1]

In the image above, the text looks somewhat blurry, the characters are not sharply defined.  The image below shows normal text in the background, and degraded text and a corrupted warning triangle in the window.

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Can you clarify the "different" resolution?  Is 1920x1080 the native resolution?  Do you know, or can you estimate, the resolution being used (can we assume it's lower)?  Is it simply a difference in resolution, or is the display degraded in other ways (for example, text characters crudely formed)?

Comment: Well it might not even be a resolution problem, but if it is then it's lower. It's just that my eyes hurt when i look at the text for too long. It looks like you took the same words and placed them on top of the original but slightly to the side. It's kinda blurry. But the windows warning triangle for example looks like it has some squars on it, like a lower res.

Comment: This would be much easier to solve if people could see a screenshot.  Can you capture one (if the problem doesn't show up in a screengrab, take a photo)?  Post a link to it at any publicly accessible sharing site, like imgur.com, and someone will embed it for you.  If you "address" a comment to me by including @fixer1234, I'll receive an alert to your posting and will be happy to do it.

Comment: @fixer1234 
http://imgur.com/2XfvDIg,EV10nId#1
the second one shows the difference between normal and blurry and the triangle i ment

Comment: For whatever the reason, Windows no longer scales legacy apps correctly when you have an HD display (HD being more than 72 dpi) and change the default 100% resolution. It can be fixed for individual apps in the "Compatibility" tab of the Properties sheet but that's unfeasible when most apps look like crap. I'd also love to know about a proper solution (if any).

Comment: Is ClearType enabled? Windows fonts look really bad without it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario where can I find this Properties sheet....

Comment: @Navin I did that but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/

> Windows 10 is using another scaling method for DPI as in Windows
>   Vista, 7, 8 and 8.1. At some point we can understand Windows why they
>   changed the DPI scaling in Windows 10. It is probably ment to support
>   mobile devices more easy.

---

> The SIMPLE fix: Right-click on the shortcut to your application that
>   has blurry fonts, then select 'Properties'. Then tab 'Compatibility'.
>   Then enable 'Disable display scaling on high DPI settings' and hit
>   'Apply'. then restart your application, and you see it will look good.

---

The same address presents a small program that would theoretically fix the problem at system level. I have not tried it though. The per-program fix works for me.